# Add class to a different table when radio button is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

The class `highlight` is added to the parent table of whichever radio button is selected.

```js
$('.logo-group').click(function() {
  $(".logo-group").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
$('input:radio:checked').trigger('click');
```

```css
#logo-options .image {
  opacity: .5;
}

table.container.highlight {
  border: 1px solid #aaa !important;
}

table.container.highlight .image {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#custom-logo-group {
  opacity: .5;
}

#custom-logo-group.highlight {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="logo-options" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="">
        <table class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              <div class="title">Default Logo</div>
              <div class="image"><img src="https://osticketawesome.com/+current/scp/images/ost-logo.png" alt="Default Logo"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
              <div class="toggle">
                <input type="radio" value="choose-theme" id="radio3" name="logo-radio" class="switch logo-group" />
                <label for="radio3">&nbsp;</label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              <div class="title">Custom Text</div>
              <div class="image"><img src="https://osticketawesome.com/+current/scp/images/ost-logo.png" alt="Custom Text"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
              <div class="toggle">
                <input type="radio" value="choose-theme" id="radio4" name="logo-radio" class="switch logo-group" checked />
                <label for="radio4">&nbsp;</label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              <div class="title">Custom Logo</div>
              <div class="image"><img src="https://osticketawesome.com/+current/scp/images/ost-logo.png" alt="Custom Logo"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
              <div class="toggle">
                <input type="radio" value="choose-theme" id="radio5" name="logo-radio" class="switch logo-group" />
                <label for="radio5">&nbsp;</label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="custom-logo-group" class="">hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So far so good.

But I additionally want the class `highlight` to be added to ***another*** table with ID `custom-logo-group` when radio button `radio5` selected = true.

Comment: So doooo eeeeet!  `this.id === 'radio5' && this.checked => do stuff`

Comment: I lack the jQuery prowess that you seem to think I should have.

Comment: That's not jQuery.  That's vanilla javascript conditional logic.  And you are already using selectors in your logic, and toggleClass in your logic, so you have demonstrated how to do what you want, once you've figured out the conditional to test the case in which you should do it in.